# How to add more that one belongs_to to same table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have student table in Rails

```
class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :students do |t|
      t.belongs_to :school, index: true, foreign_key: true,null: false
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true, foreign_key: true,null: false
      t.belongs_to :division, index: true, foreign_key: true,null: false

      t.belongs_to :section, index: true, foreign_key: true,null: false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

, Now I want to add two foriegn key into that table

1st father , where father belongs to user table and in DB its role save is father

2nd mother , where mother belongs to user table and in DB its role save is mother

I am new to rails and try this

```
t.belongs_to :user, index: true,foreign_key:  'father_id',null: false
```

but it did not create father_id in student table

I want to access father like student.father. Please help me to do this

Comment: try `t.belongs_to :father, index: true,foreign_key:  'father_id',null: false`. And in the `Student` table you have to declare the association like `belongs_to :father, foreign_key: "father_id", class: "User"`

Comment: The above should be the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking at is a [self referential join](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins):

```
#db/migrate/create_parents____.rb
class CreateParents < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      change_table :students do |t|
         t.references :father, index: true, null: false
         t.references :mother, index: true, null: false
      end
   end
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :father, class_name: "User"
   belongs_to :mother, class_name: "User"
end
```